# Initializing an enum like if it where a class for avoiding a cast

Tags: c++

Today I found some syntax that I haven't seen before.

```
enum MyEnum{    FOO = 0,    ABA,    DADA, }
....

MyEnum test;
std::uint8_t some_number(3);

test = MyEnum(some_number);
```

What exactly happens here? the enum will be treated like a class? or is this only a cast?

Comment: When `T` is a type, `T(x)` is the same as `(T)x`. Enums are integral types, so they can be converted.

Comment: So this is only an old C style cast?

Comment: Yes, it is just a cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
test = MyEnum(some_number);
```

Here the `some_number` is explicitly converting to enum type. The result of such a conversion is undefined unless the value is within the range of the enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

MyEnum is declared as having three values:

```
FOO: 0
ABA: 1
DADA: 2
```

`std::uint8_t` `some_number` is initialized to the value `3`. This value is than cast to a `MyEnum` value. Because there exists no mapping from value `3` to a `MyEnum` value, you probably get an undefined `Enum` value in `test`